# C# code to passing json data with WebService

Tags: c#

```
response = requests.patch( "https://<manageraddress>/api/admin/configuration/v1/conference/1/", auth=('<user1>', '<password1>'), verify=False, data=json.dumps({'pin': '1234'}) https://tsmgr.tsecurevideo.com/api/admin/configuration/v1/conference/1/"
```

I have tried

```
  HttpWebRequest httpWReq =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://tsmgr.tsecurevideo.com/api/admin/configuration/v1/conference/2/"));
   Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
   string postData = "{\"pin\":\"1234\"}";
   byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

   httpWReq.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
   httpWReq.Method = "POST";
   httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json";//charset=UTF-8";

   string credentials =   Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("admin" + ":" + "password"));
   httpWReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
   httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;


   Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream();
   stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
   stream.Close();

   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
   string s = response.ToString();
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
```

I am getting the error

> The remote server returned an error: (501) Not Implemented.

Comment: What steps have you take to try to diagnose the problem yourself? What exception are you getting? Where is it thrown? What is the stack trace? See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx for some pointers on how to ask a question that will generate the best response

Comment: is possible that there is an error in the implementation of the method?

Answer (score 0):

try to send credentials in this way

```
string auth = string.Format("{0}:{1}", "admin","password");
string data = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(auth));
string credentials= string.Format("{0} {1}", "Basic", data );
httpWReq.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = credentials;
```

refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii(v=vs.110).aspx) for documentation in Encoding.ASCII

Answer (score 0):

From the [HTTP spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> **501 Not Implemented**
>
> The server does not support the functionality required to fulfill the request. This is the appropriate response when the server does not recognize the request method and is not capable of supporting it for any resource.

Sounds like the server doesn't support the PATCH method.